# How to fix the Assertion problem in Nodejs when testing the javascript code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is the javascript code of the program to print odd number or even
number between x and y inserted numbers, if x>y, then even numbers are
printed otherwise odd numbers are printed in the array:

```
 const number_game = (x,y) => {
 var myArray = [];

 if(x>y){
     for(i=y+1;i<x;i++){
       if(i%2==0){
           myArray.push(i);
       }
     }
 }
 else{
     for(i=x+1;i<y;i++){
         if(i%2 !=0){
             myArray.push(i);
         }
     }
 }
 return myArray;
 }
 console.log(number_game(2,12));
```

here is my Test in NodeJS using Assertions

```
 let assert = require("chai").assert;
 describe('Challenge', function() {
   it('should return the right array', function() {
     assert.deepEqual(number_game(2,12), [3, 5, 7, 9, 11]);
     assert.deepEqual(number_game(0,0), []);
     //   assert.deepEqual(number_game(0,0), []);
   });
 });
```

this is the Error Message of the program

```
 expected [ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(11) ]
```

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/5xafyope/

Comment: thank you for the correction, but it's still crashing for me because i'm using an online compiler , so no need of HTML code for me, i'm using only Javascript and Nodejs. if you have time you can help me out to find a clear solution in javascript and nodejs (for testing )

Comment: My fiddle proves that the code you are testing is correct. Any errors you are getting are caused by the environment you are testing in. Please help us understand what that environment is.